# dblclick event in row table and redirect to edit view MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How can I redirect to edit view the row I double click in table?

I actually successfully pass the ID of the row to the controller but I can't redirect the view for edit.

```
$('#tableData td').dblclick(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var row = $this.closest("tr");
            var id = row.data("id");

            $.ajax({
                data: { id: id },
                url: '@Url.Action("PCApplicationRecordEdit","EmployeePCAssignment")',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (result)
                {

                }
            });
        });
```

That is the jquery where it triggers when I double click the row in the table.

```
public ActionResult PCApplicationRecordEdit(PCApplicationRecordModels model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
```

the method view for my edit

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PCApplicationRecordEdit(string id)
    {
        /*I do things here*/

        return View("PCApplicationRecordEdit", model);
    }
```

But even though I have this `return View("PCApplicationRecordEdit", model);`, It still not redirecting to the edit view.

Can someone help me?

Comment: The whole purpose of ajax is to stay on the same page (it does not redirect to another view). If you want to redirect, the build a url and use `location.href = url;`

Comment: how am I supposed to it? removing the ajax then replacing it with `location.href = url`?

Comment: `var url = '@Url.Action("PCApplicationRecordEdit","EmployeePCAssignment")' + '/' + id;` But your methods do not make sense. You just need to delete the first one (with parameter `PCApplicationRecordModels model`) and make the second one a `[HttpGet]`

Comment: Ok I get it.. ..I'll give you feedback later.

Comment: A moment @StephenMuecke how about my return in view? do I have to change it? or It will still remain like that?

Comment: You have not shown the code in the controller, but it probably wont change. (assuming you are building a `PCApplicationRecordModels` model based on the value of `id`). And it just needs to be `return View(model);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105536/discussion-between-qwerzxcxyz-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1):

You would be set the **ondblclick()** function directly on **tr** element inside **foreach** and set a little javascript function to call.

See the example with Customer table on razor construction

```
...
 <tbody>
  @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr ondblclick="goToEdit(@item.CustomerID)">
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerCode)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerName)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

On script section:

```
<script>
  function goToEdit(s) {

        location.href = "@Url.Action("Edit", "Customer", new {id= "cid" })".replace("cid",s.toString()); 
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using an **ajax** call that returns said view.

If you want to redirect the page using ajax calls in javascript, try to return a javascript command to redirect to said page. something like:

```
return JavaScript("window.location = 'EmployeePCAssignment/PCApplicationRecordEdit'");
```

In your controller.

(Ajax calls don't refresh or reload the page, it's used to get data from the server while you stay on the same page. That's why it didn't work, nothing happened with the data you retrieved.)

If you don't have additional logic in your controller needed when you move to your edit then it might be better to replace the ajax call with the:

```
window.location = 'EmployeePCAssignment/PCApplicationRecordEdit'
```

Comment: so that's why? and what will happen to my ajax code?
am I just gonna remove it? and replace my controller return?

Comment: (edited my answer slightly) If you don't need additional logic in your controller than just replace the call